# How to sort items alphabetically having same priority value?

Tags: c#, linq

We have a list of items with a priority property (1,2,3,...). We sort them via

```
itemList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Priority).ToList();
```

Here is some example input:

```
banana    1
apple     1
item3     2
item4     3
item5     0
```

There are scenario where items having same priorities(apple, banana) in this case wanted to sort same priorities items alphabetically.

```
item4     3
item3     2
apple     1
banana    1
item5     0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ThenBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.thenby?view=net-5.0):

```
itemList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Priority).ThenBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/VqZod8